# What is the point of the Schröder-Bernstein Theorem?

Tags: functions, fixed-point-theorems

I'm awfully sorry to be asking a question such as this, especially given the amount of times Schröder-Bernstein has been a highly useful citation when proving bijections or other similar things.

Nonetheless, I hope it is sufficient excuse to say that I am unfortunately a disaffected student merely trying to make sense of the purpose of what is taught to them.

Why don't we just take it as obvious that there is a bijeciton between two sets if they have at least as many elements as one another? Even setting aside antisymmetry as one of the properties which defines the $\leq$ relation, an injeciton means that you have mapped every element of a set into another. So, if every single element in one set can uniquely map to another, and the same goes for the latter, surely it's trivial that there would be a bijection between the two? Why do we need to develop a 'convoluted' proof to show this? What am I missing?

Comment: "surely it's trivial that there would be a bijection between the two" Why not try to give a short proof of this? The whole point of SB is that, after all, it turns out to be *not* that trivial.

Comment: If there is a surjection from $A$ to $B$ and a surjection from $B$ to $A$, then would you say it's surely trivial that there's a bijection between them?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1058/when-does-cantor-bernstein-hold

Comment: @ErickWong, admittedly, your wording makes it less trivial. However, I also know that if I have a surjection from $A$ to $B$, then I must have an injeciton from $B to $A$, and the same for the inverse, once more returning us to the trivial notion. Although perhaps this is a little subjective on my behalf.

Comment: @fruitlessfruitjuice Getting injections from surjections this way requires the axiom of choice; in ZF (= set theory without choice) it's consistent that there is a pair of sets admitting surjections each way but no bijection. But SB is provable without choice ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber not exactly a formal proof, but an example off the top of my head: if I have two bags, and I want to figure out if they have the same number of elements, then I can take out an element from bag $A$ and pair it off with an element form bag $B$ which I take out. If bag $B$ does not empty before bag $A$, then I must have an injection from $A$ to $B$. If they both empty at the same time, then clearly the bags have the same amount of elements (there is a bijeciton between the two).

Comment: Infinity is hard

Comment: Yes but if you have a bag with all the integers and a bag with all the natural numbers then in order I draw from each bag the $n$-th natural number. By the ""end"" one bag will have all the negative integers and the other will be empty. I cannot conclude that the integers are a larger set since there are just as many integers as natural numbers

Comment: @NoahSchweber when you say 'this way' do you mean by the pairing off method I had detailed? Is the main idea behind the significance of ZF that it holds without AofC?

Comment: @Math_Images_Only But we can construct a bijective mapping from $\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{Z}$, it just depends on the order in which we list each element (and how we construct $\mathbb{Z}$)? Yes, I get the point that when dealing with infinities, the bag doesn't empty, but the principle of being able to 'pair off' each element of the bag with elements in another bag still holds?

Comment: You're missing an *n* in Ber**n**stein

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you! I've just fixed it :)

Comment: «Why don't we just take it as obvious that...» are great last words, if not very original.

Comment: I suspect that your intuition is derived from finite sets. Going to infinite is a leap.

Comment: @fruitlessfruitjuice Even ignoring the (fatal) issues pointed out re: choice of injection, your proposed proof assumes that both sets can be well-ordered. What if they can't be? (Incidentally, assuming that all sets can be well-ordered - that is, assuming the axiom of choice - we *can* actually make a version of your argument work: just pick well-orderings of the two sets of *minimal length*).

Comment: But it isn't obvious that you can always totally order a set, for example how would you totally order the set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: To elaborate on @Math_Images_Only's question, it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ cannot be linearly ordered (let alone well-ordered).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Math_Images_Only, thank you both for your responses. I'm happy to formulate a brief answer to my quesiton below along the lines of the fact that a proof of Schröder-Bernstein is necessary insofar as it allows for us to prove bijections when ordering is not possible. Would this be alright, and accurately capture your points?

Comment: @fruitlessfruitjuice I think that'd be great!